# Angular 14 running the project with AOT enabled- error NG6002: 'SharedUiModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class

Tags: shared

All the import statements are mentioned in that SharedUiModule still throwing an error

I have tried removing the node_modules and installing it again. But didn't work. Can anyone please help me with this.

Wherever that sharedUiModule is imported getting the same error it does not appear as a NgModule Class.